# Why does every convex quadrilateral have diagonals that cross each other?

Tags: geometry

I know that a polygon is convex iff there exists diagonals between any two nonadjacent vertices.

> This has me thinking... Why does every convex quadrilateral have diagonals that cross each other?

I believe this holds true, but I am not sure why.

Comment: What is your definition of convex quadrilateral?

Comment: A quadrilateral is a four-sided shape and a convex polygon is where every angle is less than $180^\circ$.

Comment: Here a quadrilateral cannot have two sides cross each other and the edges are straight. Does that help?

Comment: Try this definition: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Convexity/What_is_a_convex_set%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral. Here we know point $C$ lies on the interior of $\angle{DAB}$. The proof as to why this holds is given [here](https://mathed.byu.edu/~dsiebert/mthed362/documents/LP19TrapezoidProof.pdf) (it discusses trapezoids but an analogous argument can be made for this). Now, $C$ can lie on one of two sides of $\overleftrightarrow{DB}$ and clearly $C\notin \overleftrightarrow{DB}$. Here $C$ cannot lie on the side of $A$ because $\angle DCB$ would form a reflex angle for the parallelogram. Thus, $C$ lies on the side of $\overleftrightarrow{DB}$ which does not contain the point $A$. This implies $\overline{CA}\cap \overline{DB}$ at a point which is where the diagonals meet.